# f is Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The function $f$ is defined as $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$f(x)=\begin{cases}0\text{ ; } x\in [0,1]\cap (\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q)\\ x_n\text{ ; } x=q_n\in [0,1]\cap (\Bbb Q)\end{cases}$

where {$x_n$} is a sequence such that $
\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n\text {}$ = $0$ and $0 \le x_n \le 1$ for all $n$ and {$q_n$} is a sequence s.t. $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] =\{q_n:n \in N\}$ (an enumeration of the rationals in the unit interval).

Can we show that $f$ is Riemann integrable and that $\int_0^1f(x)$ dx=0?

I am really clueless about this. Kindly help or give some hints.

Thanks

Comment: I guess you want $a=0$ and $b=1$?

Comment: I guess you also want both occurrences of $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ to be $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff yes sorry for the typo.

Comment: @AndreasBlass the second condition should be Q instead of (R\Q)

Comment: If you've never done a problem like this before, then it's difficult to come up with the idea - however, I'm sure that you've seen some sort of variation, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. We need to find a partition so that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$ for a given $\epsilon.$ By the conditions, for any $\epsilon > 0,$ there exists $N$ such that for $n\ge N,\, x_n < \epsilon/2$. For $m < N,$ cover $q_m$ by including $[q_m - \epsilon/4N, q_m + \epsilon/4N]$ in $P$ (or something smaller to make sure the intervals don't intersect except at endpoints). The rest of the partition doesn't matter.

Note that $L(f,P) = 0$ for any partition since any interval contains an irrational number. In our partition, $\begin{equation*}
U(f,P) \le \frac{\epsilon}{2N}\cdot N + 1 \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon,
\end{equation*}$
so we are done. The first term comes from the length of each interval covering $q_m$ times the number of such intervals (using also that $x_m \le 1$), and the second comes from the length of the remaining intervals being less than $1$ and $x_n < \epsilon/2.$

Comment: Another method is to show that $f$ is continuous at all irrational points and discontinuous only on a subset of the rationals, so Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability will finish the problem.

Comment: thanks but how to show the boundedness?

Comment: what do you mean boundedness? I've proved everything you need